# how to address HADOOP_CONF_DIR files(yarn-site.xml, ...) from client to remote hdfs directory

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have one unique Yarn cluster which is used by many remote clients that submits spark applications to it.
I need to set `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variable in each client as my master is yarn(`--master yarn`), but i don't want to copy it from Yarn cluster to each client separately.
I want to put `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` in hdfs which is accessible for all clients.
Now, how can i address this environment variable (`HADOOP_CONF_DIR`) in each client to access and read from hdfs URL.

for example when I used like this:

`export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=hdfs://namenodeIP:9000/path/to/conf_dir`

or in python code I used:

`os.environ['HADOOP_CONF_DIR']=hdfs://namenodeIP:9000/path/to/conf_dir`

both of them  don't work for me.

what is the correct form?
and where should I set this? in code, in spark-env.sh, in terminal, ...

Comment: That sounds like putting carriage in front of a horse -- your clients need `xxxx-site.xml` files contained in `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` to access HDFS from which you want them to read these files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. You need that variable to also know HDFS namenode location, not only YARN.

If you have control over the client machines, you could use tools like Syncthing to distribute the files automatically, but that assumes your intra-cluster connection values are the same as external access (i.e. use FQDN values in all server addresses).

Comment: thank you for your answer, I wnt to know if it is not possible even if Im giving the hdfs url. because in many cases we can interact with hdfs with hadoop_conf_dir by using just the url with different ports of hadoop.

Comment: Using namenode address directly will only work if you don't have a highly available setup (i.e. standby namenode)

Comment: One solution I've used before is publish JAR or Python dependencies to local Artifactory that include these files or a simple function for creating a SparkSession/SparkContext with the appropriate Hadoop configuration. Artifactory isn't required, but the dependency can then be managed along with other Spark libraries